# ANTLR4 generating code for the last expression entered in curly braces

Tags: while-loop, compiler-construction, antlr4

I'm building a language primarily used for calculation purposes. It is a small language with C like syntax but extremely limited functionality. For the past few days, I've been trying to generate code that is encapsulated in curly braces however whenever I enter `expressions` in curly braces, the code generated is always for the last expression entered. It is supposed to work on a `while` loop.

For example:

```
while( true )
{
    // some expressions (not using any variables for simplicity)
    5 + 9;
    8 - 10;
    4 * 6;
}
```

However the code generated only takes into account the last expression (4 * 6) in this case.

The link to the code:
https://codeshare.io/GL0xRk

And also, the code snippet for handling curly braces and some other relative code:

```
calcul returns [String code]
@init
{
$code = new String();
}
@after
{
System.out.print($code);
for( int i = 0; i < getvarg_count(); ++i )
{
    System.out.println("POP");
}
System.out.println("HALT");
}
: (decl
{
// declaration
$code += $decl.code;
})*
NEWLINE*
{
$code += "";
}
(instruction
{
// instruction, eg. x = 5; 7 * 4;
$code += $instruction.code;
System.err.println("instruction found");
})*
;

whileStat returns [String code]
: WHILE '(' condition ')' NEWLINE* block
{
int cur_label = nextLabel();
$code = "LABEL " + cur_label + "\n";
$code += $condition.code;
$code += "JUMPF " + (cur_label + 1) + "\n";
$code += $block.code;
$code += "JUMP " + cur_label + "\n";
$code += "LABEL " + (cur_label + 1) + "\n";
}
;

block returns [String code]
@init
{
$code = new String();
}
: '{' instruction* '}' NEWLINE*
{
System.err.println("block found");
$code += $instruction.code;
System.err.println("curly braces for while found");
}
;
```

And the compiler code generated:

```
while(true)
{
 5+9;
 8-10;
 4*6;
}
block found
curly braces for while found
instruction found
LABEL 0
PUSHI 1
JUMPF 1
PUSHI 4
PUSHI 6
MUL
POP
JUMP 0
LABEL 1
HALT
```

I have a feeling that the `$code` is always reinitialized. Or maybe it's because I have `instruction*` in two different rules. I'm not sure how else to handle this problem. All help is much appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyway, it looks like your problem is that `$instruction` in `block`'s action only refers to the last instruction because the block is outside of the `*`, so the action only gets run once.

You can either move the action inside the `*` like you did in the `calcul` rule or you can put all the instructions in a list with `instructions+=instruction*` and then use `$instructions` in the action (or better: a listener or visitor).

PS: I strongly recommend to use a listener or visitor instead of having actions all over your grammar. They make the grammar very hard to read.

Comment: I have used a visitor before but since I'm learning, I'd really like to have the code inline. I'm sorry but I didn't get where you suggested moving the `instruction`. If i move the curly braces inside the with instruction then that would imply I could have several curly braces for one while loop?

Comment: @simptri I didn't suggest moving the `instruction`. I suggested either moving the action inside the `*` (like you did in `calcul`) or writing `instructions+=instruction*` where you're currently writing `instruction*` (so not moving anything, just adding `instructions+=` in front of `instruction`).

Comment: so i added `instructions+=instruction*` and tried `$instructions.code` (which gives error) and `$instruction.code` (which still references to the last exprerssion) unfortunately.

Comment: @simptri As I said, `instructions+=instruction*` will gather the instructions in a list. You can't call `.code` on a list (as the error message tells you). You'll need to iterate over the list.

Comment: thank you so much, actually moving the action inside the (*) did solve the problem. now I have `'{' (instruction{/* action */})* 'NEWLINE*; }'`..once again, thank you for your time..
Furthermore, using $instructions.get(index).code also worked..sorry, I'm new to this so it took a while to sink in